# Return Boolean Value Validation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex

I need to check the return values whether Boolean or not?. Value may be return the followings

```
0
1
true
false
```

Comment: Should validation be made in c# or javascript?

Comment: If you're talking about C# (as implied by the first tag) then two of those things aren't booleans.  Can you be more specific about what you're doing and what it has to do with the tags you've using in the question?

Comment: @David `true`/`false` technically can be, if the OP uses [Convert.ToBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: validation needed in both c# and java script

Comment: Please clarify your question, you are interested in the datatype of the returned value rather in the value itself, right ???

Comment: i want to check the function return value whether its boolean or not

Comment: You want 0,1,true,false to return TRUE?

Comment: yes. 0,1,true,false means its return TRUE

Comment: @James I rest my case ;) See my javascript answer.

Comment: @Madhavan and given these values in the context of JS are they all primitive types i.e. `0`/`1` are `int` and `true`/`false` are not strings?

Comment: @James If you fix your answer by my answer, at least give me +1 for my answer. I don't understand Y I got -3 :\ 10X

Comment: yes @James you are right.

Comment: @Madhavan See my javascript answer man.

Comment: @Madhavan your question is rather confusing then :S either you want to test whether the values *can be treated/converted* to a boolean OR you want to test whether a value is a real boolean - which is it? If it's the latter then `0`/`1` will never pass because they are `int` not `bool`.

Comment: @James Forget Boolean. He want to check the 4 options above.

Comment: @justtal the question clearly states "*I need to check the return values whether Boolean or not?*" - what you are suggesting is as long as the value is equal to `0`/`1`/`true` or `false` then it returns `true` - that's not the same as returning true if the value is in fact a boolean type, what if there was a change to the compiler that meant `0`/`1` no longer convert naturally to a boolean? That would completely change the context of the test because you would now be testing *if the value is an integer of 0 or 1 OR the value is a boolean true or false*.

Comment: @James His question was confusing :) therefor the long chatting here. I think we both right... have a nice day man.

Comment: @James I'm replacing the -1 to +1 for the effort :)

Comment: @justtal thanks, however, I am half tempted to delete my answer because the OP still hasn't really clarified the question.

Comment: @Madhavan, I don't understand why my answer got a -2. Anyways, I am deleting my answer, because there is no point in continuing on this question because the question itself is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, the `Convert.ToBoolean` method should have you covered for both scenarios where you want to test a `string` or an `int`, there are various [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.ToBoolean%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) i.e.

```
var boolVar = Convert.ToBoolean("true"); // true
boolVar = Convert.ToBoolean(1); // true
```

In JavaScript, you could use

```
var bool = new Boolean(true); // true
bool = new Boolean(1); // true
bool = new Boolean(false) // false
bool = new Boolean("Hello") // true (one of the caveats)
```

However, there are some [caveats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) to using `Boolean` you should be aware of - be sure not to confuse a `Boolean` object (i.e. `var x = new Boolean(...)`) with a boolean primitive (i.e. `var x = false`). If you are simply looking to check whether your value *is* a boolean i.e. not interested in it's value, then it would probably be more reliable to explictly check that e.g.

```
if (x === "true" || x === "false" || x === 1 || x === 0) {

}
```

Comment: This is wrong answer man. He only wanna know if the variable is Boolean. He want 0,1,true,false to return TRUE!

Comment: @justtal that's your interpretation of the question, the value of the boolean can come in various different forms i.e. `string`/`int` - both of which will never evalulate to `boolean` like you have suggested in your answer. The data needs to be converted first and THEN evaluated.

Comment: "I need to check the return values whether Boolean or not" simple sentence... :)

Comment: @justtal like I said, a `x = "true"` is not the same as `x = true` therefore the most reliable way is to convert the value to the primitive type and then evaluate. In otherwords, how can you be sure that `"true"` is a boolean value unless you convert it to one OR alternatively explicitly check for it i.e. `if (x === "false" || x === 0 ...)`

Comment: But he doesn't want to convert! "true" is wrong for him. Maybe he is doing validation of data and if it is not boolean it suppose to be null???

Comment: @justtal exactly, so to check if something is `true` or `false` it has to be converted to a boolean.... unless you *explictly* check for said values i.e. `if (x === 1 || x === 2 || x === "true" || x === "false")`. The question isn't really clear in that respect hence why it's been put on hold.

Comment: You don't understand :) You answer will return TRUE even if the value will be "my string value" but he doesn't want it...

Comment: @justtal I do understand, that's why my answer explicitly mentions *there are some caveats to using `Boolean` you should be made aware of* and even went to the trouble of showing an example... My JS example was more if you wanted to check the `value` rather than just if it was a boolean (with it defaulting to `true`). The C# example is applicable for both scenarios though. In any case the question was not clear enough.

Answer (score -2):

Ill I can give you with what you provided is the below regex which matches your provided values

```
(0|1|true|false)
```

Comment: You really don't need a regex for this.

Comment: Probably not but doesn't mean you cant use it

Answer (score -2):

Both C# you can use your custom converter

```
public class BooleanConverter : System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter
{
    public override bool IsValid(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            byte b = Convert.ToByte(value);
            return b == 0 || b == 1 || base.IsValid(context, value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return base.IsValid(context, value);
        }
    }
}
```